# internal storage running low

Tags: applications, app2sd, insufficient-memory

I am not very technologically advanced so bear with me. I need to move more apps to my SD card from internal storage because I am running low on internal storage space. I have moved very few apps to my Sd card with application manager but the majority of the apps have the option greyed out. After the apps updated  the move to SD card option remained greyed out. How can I free up space? I have a 16 GB SD card so its a little frustrating that I can't use it.

Comment: Emily, I've just added two more tags to your question. You might want to check their tag-wikis, which contain some first-aid ([app2sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) and [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)).

Comment: My phone is the LG Optimus F3

Answer (score 1):

If the "Move" option is greyed out, it can mean either, or both of the following:

1) The application was granted device administration privilege previously. To disable device administration for an application, go to **Menu | Settings | Security | Device Administrators** (Please note these options vary between Android versions, but they should be similar). Then, the "Move" option should be enabled to allow you to move data to your external SD card (i.e. microSD card).

or

2) The application was designed to ONLY RUN in internal memory. This is set in the application by the developer and there's nothing you can do about it (unless you know how to reverse-engineer the application). The reason for this is that some Android functions only work if they are executed from the internal storage area.

Sometimes, you will have applications that do both of the above. So, if you cannot move an application, the above are the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get more storage space without moving your apps is to download Norton Clean (the only good Norton app) and clear your cache and junk files. On my first time using this it freed up over two gigabytes of storage space.